# Wordpress & non-wordpress: 500 Internal Server Error when use $_POST, $wp_session and custom SQL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, post

I'm developing a custom profiles to my users.

My intention are save the data storage in `$wp_session`, into a custom database.

From JavaScript, check if the `$idsession`, and `$url` exists, if this exist show "*Delete Button*", else show "*Add Button*" (I've 3 action buttons - Marcador - Favoritos - "Recomendar". The latter button isn't configured yet).

---

This is my **Javascript code**:

```
function accion(t){
  $.ajax({
    url : '/action.php',
    data: { accion:t },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(d){
      switch(d.tipo){
        case 'chequear':
        if(d.estadofav==1){
            $('#favoritos').html('<i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Borrar Favorito');
            $('#favoritos').attr('data-accion','eliminar-favorito');
        }
        if(d.estadomarc==1){
            $('#marcador').html('<i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Borrar Marcador');
            $('#marcador').attr('data-accion','eliminar-marcador');
        }
        break;
        case 'agregar-favorito':
        if(d.addfav==1){
            $('#favoritos').html('<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Añadir Favorito');
            $('#favoritos').attr('data-accion','agregar-favorito');
        }
        else{
            $('#favoritos').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Error');
            $('#favoritos').attr('data-accion','error');
        }
        break;
        case 'eliminar-favorito':
        if(d.delfav==1){
            $('#favoritos').html('<i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Borrar Favorito');
            $('#favoritos').attr('data-accion','eliminar-favorito');
        }
        else{
            $('#favoritos').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Error');
            $('#favoritos').attr('data-accion','error');
        }
        break;
        case 'agregar-marcador':
        if(d.addmarc==1){
            $('#marcador').html('<i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i> Guardar Marcador');
            $('#marcador').attr('data-accion','agregar-marcador');
        }
        else{
            $('#marcadores').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Error');
            $('#marcador').attr('data-accion','error'); 
        }
        break;
        case 'eliminar-marcador':
        if(d.delmarc==1){
            $('#marcador').html('<i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Borrar Marcador');
            $('#marcador').attr('data-accion','eliminar-marcador');
        }
        else{
            $('#marcadores').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Error');
            $('#marcador').attr('data-accion','error');
        }
        break;
        case 'recomendar':
            $('#recomendar').html('<i class="fa fa-retweet"></i> Recomendar');
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.botones_users').on('click',function(e){
      var t = $(this).attr('data-accion');
      accion(t);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
});
accion('chequear');
```

I send the data with ajax, using method `POST` and use a switch to check, add or delete based on the action.

This are loaded in the `footer.php` of my wordpress site.

In my custom PHP file, I include the core files of wordpress, the database connection and the switch to decode the JSOn and make the action indicated.

---

Here is my **PHP file**:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('wp-load.php');
require_once("wp-config.php");
require_once('funciones-perfil.php');
$wp->init(); 
$wp->parse_request(); 
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals(); 
$wp->send_headers();

wp_session_start();
global $wp_session;

function chequear_favorito(){
  $cf = 0;
  $check_fav = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT user_id, url 
        FROM favoritos WHERE user_id ='".$wp_session['post_actual']['id']."' 
        AND url = '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_url']."'
        ");
  if($check_fav->num_rows > 0){
        $cf = 1;
  }
  return $cf;
}
function chequear_marcador(){
  $cm = 0;
  $check_marc = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT user_id, url 
        FROM marcadores WHERE user_id ='".$wp_session['post_actual']['id']."' 
        AND url = '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_url']."'
        ");
  if($check_marc->num_rows > 0){
        $cm = 1;
  }
  return $cm;
}
function agregarfav(){
  $af = 0;
  $add_fav = $mysqli->query("
        INSERT INTO favoritos(serie,episodio,temporada,url,titulo,user_id,image, estado)
        VALUES ('".$wp_session['post_actual']['n_serie']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['n_episodio']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['n_temporada']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_url']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_titulo']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['id']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_imagen']."',
                '1'
        ")
  if($add_fav->num_rows > 0){
        $af = 1;
  }
  return $af;
}
function agregarmarc(){
  $am = 0;
  $add_marc = $mysqli->query("
        INSERT INTO marcadores(serie,episodio,temporada,url,titulo,user_id,image, estado)
        VALUES ('".$wp_session['post_actual']['n_serie']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['n_episodio']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['n_temporada']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_url']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_titulo']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['id']."',
                '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_imagen']."',
                '1'
        ")
  if($add_marc->num_rows > 0){
        $am = 1;
  }
  return $am;
}
function eliminarmarc(){
  $em = 0;
  $del_marc = $mysqli->query("
        UPDATE marcadores SET estado = '1' 
        WHERE user_id = '".$wp_session['post_actual']['id']."' 
        AND url = '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_url']."'
        AND estado = '1'
        ")
  if($del_marc){
        $em = 1;
  }
  return $em;
}
function eliminarfav(){
  $ef = 0;
  $del_fav = $mysqli->query("
        UPDATE favoritos SET estado = '1' 
        WHERE user_id = '".$wp_session['post_actual']['id']."' 
        AND url = '".$wp_session['post_actual']['e_url']."'
        AND estado = '1'
        ")
  if($del_fav){
        $ef = 1;
  }
  return $ef;
}

$_POST  = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_POST);
$_POST  = array_map('strip_tags', $_POST);
$tipo   = $_POST['accion'];
$unjson = array('metodopost' => $tipo);

switch($tipo){
        case 'chequear':
                $unjson['tipo'] = 'chequear';
                        $estado_fav = chequear_favorito();
                        $estado_marc= chequear_marcador();
                $unjson['estadofav'] = $estado_fav;
                $unjson['estadomarc']= $estado_marc;
        break;
        case 'agregar-favorito':
                $unjson['tipo'] = 'agregar-favorito';
                        $agregarfav = agregarfav(); 
                $unjson['addfav'] = $agregarfav;
        break;
        case 'eliminar-favorito':
                $unjson['tipo'] = 'eliminar-favorito';
                        $eliminarfav = eliminarfav(); 
                $unjson['delfav'] = $eliminarfav;
        break;
        case 'agregar-marcador':
                $unjson['tipo'] = 'agregar-marcador';
                        $agregarmarc = agregarmarc(); 
                $unjson['addmarc'] = $agregarmarc;
        break;
        case 'eliminar-marcador':
                $unjson['tipo'] = 'eliminar-marcador';
                        $eliminarmarc = eliminarmarc(); 
                $unjson['delmarc'] = $eliminarmarc;
        break;
        /*case 'recomendar':
                $unjson['tipo'] = 'recomendar';
                        $recomendar = recomendar(); 
                $unjson['recoestado'] = $recomendar;
        break;*/

        default:
                $unjson['estado'] = 0;
        break;
}
exit(json_encode($unjson));
```

(*I comment the case 'recomendar'*).

When I uploaded all to my server, this return **500 server error** (viewed in console).

[image]

- I try commenting the functions with SQL, return `$wp_session` correctly but 500 error.
- I try commenting the `$wp_session` and core files, this return 500 error.
- I try commenting all, excepting `$_POST`, I get: `{"metodopost":null,"estado":0}`.
- I `print_r($wp_session)` and its ok.
- The SQL its OK, all table and columns exists.

I believe the problem is the `$_POST`, but I can't find the error.

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no semicolon after every INSERT and UPDATE statement. Anyway, if you have error 500, you should check the Apache error_log - everything should be logged in it.

Comment: Ok, I added this semicolon. I use nginx, I'll check the error_log. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you use php-fpm, the error will be will be logged in php-fpm's log.

Comment: The error.log are setup in a directory. There are so mucho lines of errors, but nothings relevant. :|